# A good simple 3D environment simulation

Tags: c++, 3d, physics-engine

I need to be able to load in a 3D environment (a possibly very large file), and have a single object traverse and be controlled through the environment. Physics are not explicitly needed, but collision detection and simulated motion are required. I also need to be able to specify locations of different viewpoints mounted on the object itself. I am planning on dynamically loading the surrounding environment of the object, as the entire environment would be too big to render and have in memory all at once.

What is the best software / engine / approach to completing this project? I am running Ubuntu 10.10, and would prefer a linux solution. Any manageable amount of coding is fine, in C++ or python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally suggest [ogre](http://www.ogre3d.org/), but I also found [this article](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/tut007.html) about irrlicht that seems particularly pertinent to your case.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like managing the environment data is going to be the bulk of the work, so finding a [scene manager](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/SceneManagersFAQ) which fits the requirements of your particular environment is the main thing.

A scene manager (in [Ogre](http://www.ogre3d.org) terminology at least) is responsible for loading scene data into memory and organizing it in a way that makes rendering as quick as possible. The most basic distinction is between indoor and outdoor scene managers, but there are many varieties.

The choice depends on the nature of the environment:

- indoor, restricted view → Quake style BSP manager
- outdoor, unbounded view → landscape manager, with paging for large landscapes
- arbitrary discrete objects → some kind of octree based manager